# Get TOP5 records from each status using Linq C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a `VacancyApply` table and that table consist of Status Id's,So i need Top5 data from each Status.I want to get top 5 records of each status.Status is int like 1,2,3
**My Query**

```
 var result = (from ui in _context.VacancyApply
              join s in _context.UserProfile on ui.UserId equals s.UserId
              join x in _context.Vacancy on ui.VacancyId equals x.VacancyId
              join st in _context.Status on ui.StatusId equals st.StatusId
              where ui.UserId == userId && ui.IsActive == true
              orderby ui.StatusId
              select new VacancyApply
              {
                  VacancyApplyId = ui.VacancyApplyId,
                  VacancyId = ui.VacancyId,
                  UserId = ui.UserId,
                  StatusId = ui.StatusId,
                  VacancyName = x.VacancyName,
                  VacancyStack = x.VacancyStack,
                  VacancyEndDate = x.VacancyEndDate,
                  StatusName = st.StatusName,
                  UserName = s.FirstName

              }).ToList();
```

Comment: You should post what is not working correctly too.

Comment: @Krusty I want to limit only TOP 5 in each status

Comment: result.GroupBy(x => x.StatusId).Select(x => x.Take(5).ToList()).ToList();

Comment: Like that:   `group st by  st.StatusId into groups  select groups.select(s=> new VacancyApply {  VacancyApplyId = ui.VacancyApplyId, //...   }).Take(5)).ToList();`?

Comment: It should be select many @jdweng

Comment: Select many is not needed.  Using Select many will give a one dimensional list.  My solutions will give a two dimensional list.

Answer (score 1):

Now what I can see from the output is that it contains One `VacancyId` and One `VendorId`.
I have a feeling that you have Many to Many relationships between `Vacancy` and `Status` tables.

But nevertheless, the answer is very simple: you need to use LINQ `Take` extension method (maybe it will be good to make it follow after the `OrderBy` because just taking the last items doesn't make sense without some logic):

```cs
var output = (logic to join, filter, etc.).OrderBy(lambda).Take(N); // N is the number of
                                                               // items you want to select
```

---

Now if you want **Generally** to take the last items from `Vacancy` and only after join it with `Status` do this:

```cs
var output = Vacancy.OrderBy(lambda).Take(N).(now join, filter, etc. with other tables);
```

---

However, if you want to Group all similar Statuses in conjunction with Vacancies and only after taking the Top items, use `GroupBy`:

```cs
var output = (logic to join, filter, etc.).GroupBy(st => st.StausId).
                                          .Select(group => group.OrderBy(lambda).Take(N));
```

---